Acrobat Pro Actions Execute Javascirpt
How can I execute a curl command in Adobe Acrobat actions execute Javascript option? I have tried exec('curl -s http://myurl.com') but it doesn't work. I also tried this.submitForm(), it works but it opens up a new file.
I expect it to call the url without opening the browser.

You can't execute curl but you can perform HTTP calls. Look at the Net.HTTP documentation
